# Get the middle part after spliting by two delemeter in a string using regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Here is my String 
Hey, Mounty Camp booking for {product} is Confirmed.%0A%0AHere are the details:%0ACamp Name: {product}%0ALocation: {location}%0AType: {roomType}%0ACheckIn : {checkIn}%0ACheckOut : {checkOut}%0AGuests: {guests}%0AAddress: {address}%0AGoogle Maps Location: {mapLink}%0A%0ANet Amount: {netAmount}%0AAdvance: {advanceAmount}%0APay at Camp: {pendingAmount}

Now I need the only middle of {} these two in an array

Here I have tried by this  /{(.*?)} regular expressing but it is not working. Only it is giving the first middle part not entirely what I want.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Add g (global) flag to regex and after use this code :

```js
var str = '%0A%0AHere are the details:%0ACamp Name: {product}%0ALocation: {location}%0AType: {roomType}%0ACheckIn : {checkIn}%0ACheckOut : {checkOut}%0AGuests: {guests}%0AAddress: {address}%0AGoogle Maps Location: {mapLink}%0A%0ANet Amount: {netAmount}%0AAdvance: {advanceAmount}%0APay at Camp: {pendingAmount}';
var result = str.match(/{(.*?)}/g).map(function (val) {
    val = val.replace(/{/g, '');
    return val.replace(/}/g, '');
});
console.log(result);
```